# Play 2.1.x default catch all route

Tags: scala, playframework, routes, playframework-2.1

Is there a default catch all fallback route in Play framework? If so how can I configure it in my routes file? Currently, there are some urls that I do not want the user to call them and even if they call, I don't want that error page appearing, rather I want them to go to the landing page of my web app! Is there a way to do that in the routes configuration file?

Answer (score 8, accepted):

Simply define a route matching any path at the end of your `routes` file. Do not forget to define specific routes for your assets though, for example:

```
GET   /               controllers.Application.index
GET   /some/path      controllers.Application.someHandler
...

# End of file
GET   /favicon.ico    controllers.Assets.at(path="/public", file="img/favicon.ico") 
GET   /$file<(css|img|js|partials)/.*>    controllers.Assets.at(path="/public", file) 
GET   /$path<.*>      controllers.Application.catchall(path)
```

Any URL not matched by an earlier rule will be matched by this one.

Comment: What does the $ symbol refer to and what does the <.*> refer to?

Comment: See the [documentation](http://www.playframework.com/documentation/2.1.x/ScalaRouting) on "Dynamic parts with custom regular expressions": `$id<regex>` defines a dynamic part whose name is "id" and which must match `regex`. Here, `$path<.*>` is a dynamic path whose name is "path" and which matches any strung.

Answer (score 4):

Catch all routes makes sense when you want to do something with the path (ie. resolve it manually in your custom action), otherwise it's enough to use common `onHandlerNotFound` in your [Global object](http://www.playframework.com/documentation/2.1.x/ScalaGlobal) and redirect request wherever you want.

Comment: The global setting seems to be interesting thing to know. In the link that you mentioned, it says that the GlobalSettings.scala should be located in the default package, but I can also refer to it from the application.conf directory. In that case, can I place it in my own convenient package?

Comment: I actually tried that and kept running into errors. Here is what I did: 23  override def onHandlerNotFound(request: RequestHeader): Result = { 

24    NotFound(

25      views.html.defaultpages.notFound(request, None)

26    )

27  }                                                                                                                                        The result of the above call says that it has incompatible types

Comment: But when I did as per what is mentioned in the documentation:     NotFound(
      views.html.notFoundPage(request.path)
    ), I got a compile error saying that notFoundPage is not found. Should I write that notFoundPage?

Comment: of course, just create your own view, and use common way for rendering templates

Comment: I'm getting a warning from the compiler to use dependency injection instead of the Global object.